# po line items to grpo

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports-2010, sapb1

I have 2 condtions in my query if my line item from po (container no) having a grpo so it should display
'shipment received' if no grpo so it should display 'no shipment received' need your expertise here please.

```
SELECT
    OPOR.DocNum ,
    POR1.U_ContainerNo ,
    CASE
        WHEN POR1.U_ContainerNo IS NOT NULL THEN 'Shipment Received'
        ELSE 'No Shipment Received'
    END 
FROM
    OPOR
INNER JOIN POR1 ON POR1.DocEntry = OPOR.DocEntry 
LEFT JOIN
    OPDN ON OPOR.DocEntry = OPDN.DocEntry
LEFT JOIN
    PDN1 ON POR1.DocEntry = PDN1.BaseEntry
```

Comment: what about it isn't working exactly?

Comment: Please provide sample date and desired results

Comment: i am getting vice versa results like if grpo punched it is showing no shipment received and if grpo not punched it is showing shipment received

Comment: May I ask why you are left joining to OPDN and PDN1? You're not limiting them and they aren't part of your SELECT, so the best they can do is give you more rows than anticipated...